# print one line on one page with javascript or jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

I had a code which runs in a loop and it should 5 tickets on one page when I try to print it..

I want to print one ticket on one page

I am lost how to do, I am trying the following code:

```
function Printticket()
{
        $('#print .ticket_new').each(function() {
            $(this).hide();
        });
        $('#print .ticket_new').each(function() {
            $(this).show();
            window.print();
        });
}
```

code is like this

```
<div id="print">
<loop from="1" to="10" index="k">
<div id="print_1" class="ticket_new>ticket1</div>
<div id="print_2" class="ticket_new>ticket2</div>
<div id="print_3" class="ticket_new>ticket3</div>
<div id="print_4" class="ticket_new>ticket4</div>
</loop>
</div>
```

Comment: So you want to print 5 tickets in 5 pages?

Comment: Make other `div` hide when you are printing a `div`. i mean hide 2nd,3rd,4th page while printing 1st... do this dynamically through js or jquery

Answer (score 1):

Based on DA's [suggestion](https://stackoverflow.com/a/28379650/2971041), I created this:

```js
$('button').click(function() {
  $('button').hide();
  $('li').each(function() {
    $(this).css({
      "page-break-after": "always"
    });
  });
  window.print();
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div>
  <ul>
    <li>ticket1</li>
    <li>ticket2</li>
    <li>ticket3</li>
    <li>ticket4</li>
  </ul>
</div>
<button>Print</button>
```

Or check this [**fiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/preeteshjain/jwLmLjcs).

This prints 4 tickets in 4 separate pages.

Answer (score 0):

Put all your `div` in a separate hidden `iframe` (Adjust the size according to the page size) and print it.

**HTML**

`<iframe id="print" name="print"></iframe>`

**JS**

`window.frames["print"].focus();
window.frames["print"].print();`

EDIT: I just read Prabhu's comment, that's a good idea too.

Answer (score 0):

Create n number of divs.

Set height and width of each div as height/width of window.

And content the ticket content in respective divs and take print.

Example :-

HTML:

```
<div id="print_1" class="ticket_new>ticket1</div>
<div id="print_2" class="ticket_new>ticket2</div>
<div id="print_3" class="ticket_new>ticket3</div>
<div id="print_4" class="ticket_new>ticket4</div>
```

JS:

```
for(var i=1;i<=4;i++)
{
$("#print_"+i).width($(window).width());
$("#print_"+i).width($(window).height());
}
```

Now all your content can be placed on divs which occupy one page per div.

Comment: that does not seems to work, t gerenartes as 1 and then 2 and 3 and creates a lot more around 6+ pages

Answer (score 0):

In terms of formatting something for printing, this is more of a CSS issue than JS. Consider using the page-break options in CSS such as `page-break-before` or `page-break-after`: http://css-tricks.com/almanac/properties/p/page-break/